# Breeze.js WebApi 2 Startup Issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm trying to do basic setup with breeze.js server-side asp.net web api 2. I have the breeze route setup and the breeze-annotated web api controller.  Calling into the Metadata action (or any action for that matter) is throwing this error below. It's nothing to do with lazy loading of navigational properties on my entity as far as I can tell.

This error seems to be a lazy type perhaps internal to the breeze data structure? I'm referencing Breeze.WebApi2 and Breeze.ContextProvider v1.4, along with Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6

I have disabled lazy loading explicitly on my db context per the breeze documentation.
dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Thanks.

```
   ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.GetControllerMapping()   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.AddRouteEntries(SubRouteCollection collector, HttpConfiguration configuration, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__1()
  at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.EnsureInitialized(Func`1 initializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__0(HttpConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.ApplyControllerSettings(HttpControllerSettings settings, HttpConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be something with the order in which the routes were being registered.  I removed the webactivor.PreApplicationStartMethod() assembly directive added by the Breeze nuget install and manually called into the Breeze route configuration in Global.asax AFTER the standard web api routes where configured and it started working.  Setting it before appears to cause the problem.